# Connecting Raspberry Pi 4 to old VGA monitor

Tags: ubuntu, signal

I'm trying to set up an old monitor to use with my Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 20.04, but whatever options I try, my monitor doesn't detect any signal coming from raspberry.

I have original HDMI cable for RPi, and trying to connect to monitor with some more or less random adapter, precisely one visible [here](https://lanberg.pl/produkt/AD-0021-BK). My monitor is Fujitsu-Siemens L9ZA, but I guess it shouldn't be of any problem, since trying to connect with VGA to my TV (where RPi works fine with HDMI) does not work either.

Are there any configs that should help me with this particular setup? Would it be different from Raspbian's once since I'm using Ubuntu?

Comment: "whatever options I try" is not reproducible by any means.

Comment: why are you using an adapter that connects a vga computer output to an HDMI monitor?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it sure looks like you're using the wrong adapter: VGA-to-HDMI instead of HDMI-to-VGA. So get an appropriate adapter first.

I use this one:
[image: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0215/6458/products/51zf2A8p0KL._SL1000_2048x.jpg?v=1522077637]

Answer (score -1):

Edit file config.txt.

disable_overscan=0